# Why has newglossaryentry no effect depending on location

Tags: glossaries-extra

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,nomain,acronym,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[tmg]{mygloss}{tms}{tmo}{My Glossy}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{test}{
    name=test,
    description={Some text},
    type=mygloss
}

% I EXPECT TO SHOW ALSO ENTRIES FROM BELOW, i.e. test2
\glsaddall[types={mygloss}]
\printglossary[type=mygloss,title=My Weird Glossary]

\section{Something}

\lipsum[1]

\newglossaryentry{test2}{
    name=test2,
    description={Some text 2},
    type=mygloss
}

Text immediately after newglossaryentry.

\end{document}
```

yields a glossary missing the glossary entry `test2`. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default in `glossaries-extra` the macro `\newglossaryentry` isn't allowed to be used inside the document body. See the documentation of the `docdef` option:

> `docdef={⟨value⟩}` (glossaries-extra.sty)
>
> This option governs the use of `\newglossaryentry`. Available values:
>
> **`false`** `\newglossaryentry` is not permitted in the document environment (default with
> `glossaries-extra` and for Option 1 with just the base `glossaries` package);
>
> **`restricted`** `\newglossaryentry` is only permitted in the document environment if it occurs
> before `\printglossary` (not available for some indexing options);
>
> **`atom`** as `restricted` but creates the `docdefs` file for use by `atom` (without the limitations of
> `docdef=true`);
>
> **`true`** `\newglossaryentry` is permitted in the document environment where it would normally be permitted by the base `glossaries` package. This will create the `docdefs` file

(from the `glossaries-user.pdf`, page 65, subsection 2.1)

So if you're using `glossaries-extra` you'll have to use either `\usepackage[docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}` or `\usepackage[docdef=true]{glossaries-extra}` for this to work.